# postfixのmail受信時にaliasesでコマンドを実行していますが、dockerコマンドが実行できずに困っています。

Tags: docker, postfix

postfixでmail受信時にaliasesでコマンドを実行しようとしています。
コマンド実行用に作成したmail_recv.shは呼び出せているのですが、shの中でdockerコマンド（例:docker ps -a）を実行すると以下のエラーになります。

```
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

/var/run/docker.sock のアクセス権を変更したら解決はできそうなのですが、なぜ、現状のアクセス権で実行できないのかがわかりませんので、知見のある方ご教示をお願いします。

#### 状況詳細

ユーザ:ken として、bashからmail_recv.shを実行するとdockerコマンドも正常に処理できます。

確認のために、メール受信時の mail_recv.sh 内で各種コマンドを実行しました。
なお、環境変数もexportで正常に実行できる状態に合わせているつもりです。

whoami  ken

<ps -aux 抜粋>

以下のような出力となっています。

```
postfix    64384  0.0  0.4  41300  8104 ?        S    08:41   0:00 local -t unix
ken        64385  0.0  0.0   2888   964 ?        Ss   08:41   0:00 sh -c  /home/ken/mail_recv.sh > /home/ken/scriptlog.txt 2>&1
ken        64386  0.0  0.1   4360  3240 ?        S    08:41   0:00 bash /home/ken/mail_recv.sh

Current PID: 64386
Parent PIDs:（プロセスの親を遡りました）
64385
64384
61792
1
```

ken、postfix ともにdockerグループになっています。

```
docker:x:999:ken,postfix
```

##### Docker ソケットのアクセス権

dockerグループならアクセスできるはず

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0  9月 13 12:26 /var/run/docker.sock
```

※なお、docker.sockを 777 に変更すると正常に実行できます。

postfixのmain.cf で、default_privs = ken と設定しています。